# no userMetadata when writing delta table to Unity Catalog

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am using DBR 13.3 LTS. When I write a delta table to Unity Catalog with the `saveAsTable` method, and specify to also include `userMetadata`, no userMetaData is written. You can reproduce the issue with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

schema = StructType([
  StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("name", StringType(), True),
  StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)])

data = [(1, "Alice", 25),
        (2, "Bob", 30),
        (3, "Charlie", 35)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

(df
 .write
 .format("delta")
 .option("userMetadata", "test")
 .saveAsTable("catalog.schema.table")
)
```

When writing in the "classic" non-UC way directly to an absolute path, then it works:

```
(df
 .write
 .option("userMetadata", "test")
 .format("delta")
 .save("/dbfs/path/to/table")
 )
```